# \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider not found

Tags: magento-2.0

With this command:

```
sudo bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

I get this message:

> MiBPHP Fatal error:  Class 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider' not found in /home .. ecc

There is a third party module that searches for this class. On

> /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category

I don't have this model.
I have `Attribute.php`, `AttributeRepository.php`, `Tree.php` but not `DataProvider.php`

Anyway, on github, on /app/code/Magento, I see this class:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Category

why? My version is 2.0.12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means the extension is not compatible with your magento version.
You are  running 2.0.12 but the file you need was added in 2.1.

You can see it here in the 2.1-rc1 tag:  https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1.0-rc1/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Category/DataProvider.php

But it's not there in the 2.0.12 tag: https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.0.12/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Category/DataProvider.php (this will get you to a 404 page)

Comment: You are right. The mysterious thing is that online, despite the wrong version, all worked. Maybe the installation was executed incorrectly and somehow managed to work. I am convinced that by deleting the cache, everything would collapse.